# IF Statement runs first time but not the second time?

Tags: javascript, html

I made a percentage number calculator. This is my first JavaScript code but I am having trouble with it. When you run it the first time it runs with no problems but the second time it gets stuck in the IF statement and won't give you a total unless you refresh the page.

Here's the JavaScript Code:

```js
let originalAmount = document.getElementById('original_amount');
let percentage = document.getElementById('percentage');
let percentAmount = document.getElementById('percentage_amount');
let calculate = document.getElementById('calculate');

calculate.addEventListener('click', function() {
  originalAmount = Number(originalAmount.value);
  percentage = Number(percentage.value);

  if (isNaN(originalAmount) || originalAmount <= 0 || originalAmount === null) {
    alert('Please enter a valid Bill Amount')
  } else if (isNaN(percentage) || percentage <= 0 || percentage === null) {
    alert('Please enter a valid Tip Percentage')
  } else {
    let calculatedTip = percentage / 100 * originalAmount;
    percentAmount.value = calculatedTip;
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: #fdcb9e;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
}

div#calculator {
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: #0f4c75;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  padding: 15px;
}

input {
  margin-right: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 2.5px 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#calculate {
  background-color: #00b7c2;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 25px 200px 15px 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital@0;1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<main style="background-color: #1b262c;">
  <h1>Percentage of a Number Calculator!</h1>
  <div id="calculator">
    <label>Number:</label><input id="original_amount"><br>
    <label>Percentage:</label><input id="percentage"><br>
    <label>Percentage of Number:</label><input id="percentage_amount" disabled><br>
    <button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
  </div>
  <!--<script src="app.js"></script>-->
</main>
```

Comment: You are overwriting `originalAmount` and `percentage` on the first click. Every subsequent click is screwed up as a result. Don't do that.

Comment: Please reproduce the code on https://jsfiddle.net/. It will make it easier to fix the error

Answer (score 0):

After your first click, your original amount and percentage gets replaced with the calculated value. Try changing your function like below.

```js
calculate.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let originalAmount = document.getElementById('original_amount');
    let percentage = document.getElementById('percentage');
    let percentAmount = document.getElementById('percentage_amount');
    let calculate = document.getElementById('calculate');

    originalAmount = Number(originalAmount.value);
    percentage = Number(percentage.value);
    

    if (isNaN(originalAmount) || originalAmount <= 0 || originalAmount === null){
        alert('Please enter a valid Bill Amount')
    }
    else if (isNaN(percentage) || percentage <= 0 || percentage === null){
        alert('Please enter a valid Tip Percentage')
    }
    else {
        let calculatedTip =  percentage/100*originalAmount;
        percentAmount.value = calculatedTip;
    }
    
    

})
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Percent of a Number Calculator!</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital@0;1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        }
        h1 {
            color: #fdcb9e;
            font-size: 50px;
            text-align:center;
        }
        div#calculator{
            color: white;
            font-size: 35px;
            width: 800px;
            background-color: #0f4c75;
            border-radius: 25px;
            padding: 50px;
            margin: auto;
        }
        label{
            display:inline-block;
            width: 400px;
            margin-right: 25px;
            padding: 15px;
        }

        input{
            margin-right: 50px;
            width: 100px;
            height: 25px;
            padding: 2.5px 40px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #calculate{
            background-color: #00b7c2;
            color: white;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 15px;
            width: 150px;
            height: 35px;
            font-size: 25px;
            margin: 25px 200px 15px 300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #1b262c;">
    <h1>Percentage of a Number Calculator!</h1>
    <div id="calculator">
        <label>Number:</label><input id="original_amount"></br>
        <label>Percentage:</label><input id="percentage"></br>
        <label>Percentage of Number:</label><input id="percentage_amount" disabled></br>
        <button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

### you are overwriting `originalAmount` object to a number here the little change.

`originalAmount` to `originalAmountInput` and `percentage` to `percentageInput`

```js
let originalAmountInput = document.getElementById('original_amount');
let percentageInput = document.getElementById('percentage');
let percentAmount = document.getElementById('percentage_amount');
let calculate = document.getElementById('calculate');

calculate.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var originalAmount = Number(originalAmountInput.value);
  var percentage = Number(percentageInput.value);

  if (isNaN(originalAmount) || originalAmount <= 0 || originalAmount === null) {
    alert('Please enter a valid Bill Amount')
  } else if (isNaN(percentage) || percentage <= 0 || percentage === null) {
    alert('Please enter a valid Tip Percentage')
  } else {
    let calculatedTip = percentage / 100 * originalAmount;
    percentAmount.value = calculatedTip;
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: #fdcb9e;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
}

div#calculator {
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: #0f4c75;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  padding: 15px;
}

input {
  margin-right: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 2.5px 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#calculate {
  background-color: #00b7c2;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 25px 200px 15px 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital@0;1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<main style="background-color: #1b262c;">
  <h1>Percentage of a Number Calculator!</h1>
  <div id="calculator">
    <label>Number:</label><input id="original_amount"><br>
    <label>Percentage:</label><input id="percentage"><br>
    <label>Percentage of Number:</label><input id="percentage_amount" disabled><br>
    <button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
  </div>
  <!--<script src="app.js"></script>-->
</main>
```